# How to design and implement an adaptive filter for impulse noise removal?

Tags: image-processing, noise-reduction

I should design and implement an adaptive filter to remove impulse noise from medical images!
and i am new in image processing . and don't know how to design a filter!
I have checked the predefined filters... they are not what i want!
please help this is my B.S. project!

Comment: A bit vague.  I suppose you should decide if you want a linear vs. non-linear filter.  That might be a start.

Comment: as i learned about the adaptive filters , they act like linear filters in some case and like non-linear filters in the others...
what you suggest?

Comment: Can you characterize the impulse spatially?  Are they always positive or negative?  Or both?  If you have the size, I'd suggest either a linear filter to smooth it out (preserves information) or a non-linear one to remove it entirely (does not preserve all information).

Comment: yes
Corrupted pixels are often replaced with value equal to or near the maximum and minimum of the allowable dynamic range.for 8bit images 0 & 255. but i considered the noisy pixels can take a arbitrary value in dynamic range...something between 0 & 255.

Comment: Perhaps then identify corrupted pixels by a higher derivative (or change) from previous or following pixels.  Is this a 1-D or 2-D signal?

Comment: you are looking it like a signal!why?
this is a gray picture,2D dimensional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impulse noise is usually dealt using the `median` filter.
To build adaptive filter I'd use the statistics to figure if there is something to smooth within the window.

I would work on the image using windows.
In each window I'd check the median and the mean.
If they are far away from each other I'd apply the `median` filter, otherwise, apply local LPF filter of do nothing.

It is simple...